# click on android screen using python

Tags: python, android, android-emulator

I have a question: Can I click on android os with python (like windows that we can change mouse position, clicking or etc.)
like clicking in emulators as gameloop or physical smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get your question clearly, but nowadays, you can use a mouse on a phone. If your talking about operating your phone with python, it might be possible, however, why to complicated, when you've got an assistant on your phone

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to use object detection on my phone that when detection an object do something like click on special position.
for example self drive in car games or something.